# Can I apply the product rule for the following finite difference discretization

Tags: finite-difference

I would like to know if the following discretization is correct. Here D is the dispersion, C is the concentration. Both D and C are varying with space. Here n+1 represents the unknown time level. I was trying to implement a second-order implicit finite difference scheme.
[image: Applying product ruler first]

After applying the product rule, I discretized it like this
[image: Discretization]

I would like to know if this is correct.

Comment: For finite difference with uniform grid spacing, you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) an overview of derivative stencils and how to calculate them. Your first order derivatives miss a factor 1/2.

Comment: @Bort Thank you for pointing it out. I would like to know if its okay to write the products  like this.

Comment: Why should it not be okay? The upper formula is exact math, and in your discretization you then simply replace the first and second derivative wirh the standard stencils. However, Bort is right that in fact all derivatives are missing a factor 1/2.